# connecting SATA SSDs to SAS

Tags: ssd, sata, sas

Is there any performance loss when connecting a SATA SSD to a SAS controller?
Edit:
Assume the controller doesn't have SATA connectors and I use a [SATA to SAS interposer](http://www.knowledgetransfer.net/dictionary/Storage/en/SATA_interposer_board.htm).
Will there be any performance loss to either the SSD or the other drives (I have 2 146GB SAS 15K RPM Drives in RAID 1)

Answer (score 1):

From what to what? you don't say - let's assume you mean will the SSD perform at a lower level than if connected to a SATA controller - if that's the case then I'd suggest not, if the controller supports SATA then it'll act like a SATA controller so you shouldn't see any drop off. If you mean something else then please clarify.

Comment: thanks for the edit - yes, doing that would introduce latency so performance would inherently suffer - there's loads of SATA & SAS controllers about, why not pick one of those up?

Comment: how much latency are we talking about? could it be slower then a regular HDD connected directly with SAS?
also, can you recommend such a controller?

Answer (score -1):

Well, first you have to verify that you can connect the drive at all! Second, this would seem to be a simple math problem- Throughput of the SAS card's bus, divided by number of SSDs on the card / or theoretical bandwidth of each SSD, compared to a similar calculation using the SATA interface.

In terms of software, it's really 100% dependent on what you're running, what drivers you have, and what kind of server setup you have. My suggestion would be to bit the bullet, get a test set of kit, and run a benchmark.